# How does ORC delimit fields?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hdfs, storage, orc

I know this must be a silly question, but after hours' googling, I cannot get the answer.

It's easy to understand in plain text format such as csv how the delimiters work. Whilein ORC, since is is binary stored in HDFS, what would be a delimiter for a field? I was told that there is no delimiter in ORC, but I highly doubt about this statement.

Even it is stored as row groups, for each row group's one column, there can be multiple data fields, how is each field distinguished from the next one? How is each row separated from the next row? Is there a delimiter to achieve this?

Thank you for any comments!

Comment: 50 years ago, *nobody* used field delimiters, nor row delimiters. Because mainframe files used fixed-width records with fixed-width fields. And also because punch cards were basically fixed-width devices (no keyboard, no screen, no mouse, duh).

Comment: Then VARCHAR (Variable-Length character strings) were created. But still no delimiter: the field starts with a fixed-width integer, that indicates the length of the data that follows. I.e. how many bytes you must skip to find the next field. See also the concept of BIFF file format that was used by older Excel files http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/freexl-1.0.1-doxy-doc/html/Format.html

Answer (score 1):

No delimiter. It uses Stride/Stripes,

> The body of the file is divided into stripes. Each stripe is self
>   contained and may be read using only its own bytes combined with the
>   file’s Footer and Postscript. Each stripe contains only entire rows so
>   that rows never straddle stripe boundaries. Stripes have three
>   sections: a set of indexes for the rows within the stripe, the data
>   itself, and a stripe footer. Both the indexes and the data sections
>   are divided by columns so that only the data for the required columns
>   needs to be read.

Refer: [ORC](https://orc.apache.org/docs/file-tail.html#stripe-information)